# Django model default parameter in get() or filter() methods

Tags: django, django-models

My question, how to override model manager's method for passing default parameter, if it doesn't set explicitly?

Say i have a model Entry:

```
class Entry(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("user"))
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now somehow i want in all get() and filter() methods add parameter `deleted=False` if this parameter isn't set explicitly (i mean in stuff like `Entry.objects.filter(deleted=True)` default parameter shouldn't override presented one).

What i do is create EntryManager and set it as manager in Entry model.
filter() method in EntreManager:

```
def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
    deleted = kwargs.get('deleted', False)
    kwargs.update({'deleted':deleted})
    return super(EntryManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

But it doesn't work for case `deleted__in=(True, False)`, and it's not strange but i don't know ways how to do this right.
Thanks in advance.
By the way i use django 1.3.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should override the manager's `get_query_set` method, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/). In your case, you could do something like this:

```
def get_query_set(self):
    return super(EntryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(deleted=False)
```

Comment: Doing by this way for case when i explicitly set parameter deleted=True in filter it doesn't override, in query i get ....WHERE ("entry"."deleted" = False AND "entry"."deleted" = True)

Comment: @tony: You'll want to have two managers, the generic `objects` manager and the specialized filtered manager (called `deleted` or somesuch).